# How to send json list of objects using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I try to send list of object like `[{"name":"Vasya"},{"name":"Lila"}]`

It's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url
,   type: 'POST'
,   contentType: 'application/json'
,   data: data
,   success:  function(response) {
        showPopup(response.successMessage);
    }
});
```

Where `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` shows: `[{"name":"Vasya"},{"name":"Lila"}]`

But when I am checking my request in chrome debug mode the request contains `undefined=` instead correct data.

What I do wrong? Is this syntax incorrect according to JSON?

Comment: Pretty offensive user name.

Comment: @mplungjan was that supposed to be sarcastic? Or did you really mean it?

Comment: Remove the `contentType` option to send the data as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, or stringify the object as JSON to actually send JSON, now you're telling the server that whatever you're sending should be valid JSON, but you're sending `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @adeneo shouldn't the request at least contains `name=Vasya&name=Lila `though? OP mentioned Chrome is sending it as `undefined` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stringify the object when sending it so that you send JSON.

```
, data: JSON.stringify(data)
```